# flask application running on Kubernete Pods doesn't respect port in configuration

Tags: docker, flask, containers, kubernetes

I have deployed my kubernete container onto google cloud platform, everything works as expected. But one thing confused me is that I specifically set my flask application to run on port `9001` and did set `conatinerPort` to 9001 as well using `--port 9001` with `kubectl run` command. But somehow, the flask app still runs on port `80` and I was basically force to expose port `80` to my loading balancer..

Is there something I'm doing wrong or it's a bug with Kubernete?
I was using docker:python:3 image to build my pods.

[image: container configuration]
[image: log from flask app]

Comment: Share your flask code?

Comment: if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='9001')

this is how I start my flask application.

Comment: Doesn't sound like Kubernetes has anything to do with that.

Answer (score 1):

the containerPort has nothing to do with the port the flask application runs on. It is only the port that is EXPOSED by the container.

You need to check your flask application settings, where you should be able to set the port to use to run the app.

something like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9001)
```

Comment: I did that as well. the port should be either 9001 or 5000 depends on development or production. However, the flask still runs on port 80..

Comment: then you must not have changed the right setting. if you really want to run on port 80 (the app) and 9001 (outside) you can always map the port 9001 to 80 by defining containerPort to be 80 and use your Service to map 9001 to 80